# How to transform a batch replace to perl?

Tags: perl, batch-file

I have a batch replace statement, that I want to transfer to perl.
But I still want to call perl from batch, and get the result back as a variable.

```
SET TEST = "mystring"
SET modified=%TEST:"='%
ECHO %modified%  //prints: 'mystring'
```

At the end I don't want a printout, just the variable `%modified%` to work with.

How could I write the statement above in perl, so that perl takes the teststring, replaces double with single quotes and gives the result back in a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want to simply replace characters in a string? This can be done in Perl with the `tr///` operator. E.G.:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $test = q("mystring");
my $modified = $test;
$modified =~ tr/"/'/;

print "$modified\n";
```